# Script for column table count doesnt include decimals

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script to calculate the total value of all rows for a column named amount. The script is below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table thead th').each(function(i) {
        calculateColumn(i);
    });
});

function calculateColumn(index) {
    var total = 1;
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            total += value;
        }
    });
    $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total:' + total);
}
```

However, whilst this works effectively - it doesn't show the decimal places. For example, if there's a credit in the table for 2.00 GBP and a credit of 0.30p - the amount shown using the script above in the total is still 2.00 GBP.

This works with whole numbers but it seems to round down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `parseInt`, therefore you are getting rid of the decimals, use `parseFloat`, like this:

```
var value = parseFloat($('td', this).eq(index).text());
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it works.

Just a last question, the code seems to provide a total for all columns in the table - not just the amount column. For example, it totals up the date column with a number - but i just want it to do it for the amount column. Can that be fixed in that code?